# RectView doesn't move away from UIWindow

Tags: objective-c

I have the following simple code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    CGRect firstFrame = CGRectMake(300, 300, 150, 259); //CGRect is a struct not a simple object

    ExampleView *view = [[ExampleView alloc] initWithFrame:firstFrame]; //crea la view
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //colora la view

    [self.window addSubview:view];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I'm working on XCode 5.1.1 but problem is that the red rect it is showed remains in the same position despite changing the values in CGRectMake. Do you have any idea why?

EDIT

[image]

[image]

This is the code

```
#import "ExampleView.h"

@implementation ExampleView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Can you provide a picture that shows that the problem is?  Your code doesn't appear to modify the red view after setting its initial position.

Comment: Maybe I have explained in a wrong way the problem...Ok I'm going to explain better the situation

Comment: I have posted two pictures.You can see that despite the changing of the position values the square it always there in the same position

Comment: The code you posted isn't modifying or changing the frame of the red view at all.  There must be something going on inside your exampleView subclass.  When I copy and paste your code and change ExampleView to UIView I get something completely different, screenshot here http://imgur.com/mKdjpwV

Comment: Yes right...infact substituting ExampleView with its super class it works so the problem is in the sub class.

Comment: I have posted the code of the subclass ExampleView inherited from UIView. As you may see it is a simple class

Comment: Ok issues solved...inside the if I forgot to call the instance object and place it equal to frame